# Applying for a position internally after 2 months

Tags: resignation, applications

I started at a big company (30k employees worldwide, 5k+ employees in our country) 1st of Feb and the position was advertised as Data Analyst and that is what my contract says. However, when I started I was given the title Business Analyst, which does not bother me but it is the tasks that I and everyone in the team does:

- Extract data
- Correct data
- Investigate queries
- Create monthly reports
- Only work in SQL & Excel

I already hinted to the hiring manager who interviewed me that I am "looking forward to doing some data analysis which you mentioned during the interview and not these ad-hoc fire fighting activities".

His reply was "we are not there but hopefully in the future". After this I made up my mind that I want to leave as I think the future is too far away (2+ years)

Internally I noticed there are some positions and I looked up what some members had been working on and it seems to suit me better.

Next week I have a bi-weekly 1:1 with my manager (not the hiring one) who also started 1st of Feb. I am considering mentioning that this role is not suitable for me but I do like the company and want to look around internally and if that does not work out I will start to look externally.

Reading on this forum a lot of advice is essentially "Never tell your manager you are planning to leave, it wont benefit you". This makes me a bit hesitant, because I am already demotivated working in this role as it was not up to my expectations and this is affecting my private life. As finding a new job might take 2-6 months I am afraid that this might cause an even worse situation until I leave.

Comment: Does your company have any rules about internal transfers?  I've worked places where you had to be at a job at least one year before you were eligible for an internal transfer.  It's also very common for your boss to be notified when you apply internally, or require their approval for a transfer.  So, what are your company rules?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek I looked in the handbook, it actually stands I need to inform my manager before applying and that internal candidates are given higher priority than others.

Answer (score 1):

What about the manager of the other department where you want to go? Will he accept you?

First you talk to the other manager if he has a vacancy and he is willing to fill it with you. If OK then follow the rules about internal transfer.

If you don't get the other position and you are not happy with your current position, then apply for other jobs without telling anyone.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to determine if this type of transfer is possible. I have worked for companies where you couldn't transfer until 6 or even 12 months after starting a position. The system that you had to use to apply for the positions would block you from being able to apply. They could only override it if the contract was coming to an end.

These rules are designed to prevent managers from poaching good employees that other managers shepherded though the hiring process.

If a transfer this soon is allowed, then you have to determine the procedure. Some companies have procedures in place so that your current manger is the last to know. The potential new manager can see your employment file, and can process your application. Unfortunately being so new to the company there probably isn't much in your employee file. Other companies discourage the internal transfers by making your current manager one of the first to know. You will have to look at the documents provided by HR, or talk to them discretely.

I wouldn't tell my current manager that I want to leave. You might be under probationary rules. You also don't know how they will react. They could personally take it as disloyalty. Some managers hate everybody that wants to try to leave.

But if you can't transfer, or you don't want to do an internal transfer; you might want to start the process of looking at other companies.

> As finding a new job might take 2-6 months I am afraid that this might
> cause an even worse situation until I leave.

Sometimes internal transfers take that long. One time I was on a contract that was ending in 30 days. I quickly found 10 openings in the company that seemed like a good match. They were within 5 miles of my office. None responded to my application. I kept applying and got a few phone interviews.  With 2 weeks to go I was put on a special list. Then with 5 days to go. one project that was desperate found my name and resume and was able to transfer me to their project to fill a hole before a contractual deadline. Months later most of those initial applications for the transfer were still waiting at stage 1: HR review.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how the managers will react. The hiring manager I know will be furious. At the company it does not mention anything how long I have to wait before transfer but it stands I need to inform the managers before even applying.

Answer (score 0):

> I am considering mentioning that this role is not suitable for me but I do like the company and want to look around internally and if that does not work out I will start to look externally.

I was in similar situation some time back so I will tell you from my experience.

If you have made your mind to quit the company because you are not happy with the current role, I believe you should have a casual chat with your manager and be honest during the conversation. Tell him why you are interested in the Data Analytics role, how you can contribute, why and how that role matches more with your future career goals etc.

Show him that you are a potential candidate and you will be able to contribute more in that role.

If you already made your mind to quit, you should take a chance of honest discussion. The hiring manager would not want you to go if you are a good employee. They will be in equal or more loss so unless they have personal grudges with you, they would better prefer you to switch teams instead of switching the company.

> Reading on this forum a lot of advice is essentially "Never tell your manager you are planning to leave, it wont benefit you". This makes me a bit hesitant, because I am already demotivated working in this role as it was not up to my expectations and this is affecting my private life. As finding a new job might take 2-6 months I am afraid that this might cause an even worse situation until I leave.

Yes, usually, this should be the last resort to tell manager that you are planning to quit, however if you have already made your mind then there is nothing wrong in talking politely and honestly because in this case, you will have a chance to move in your desired team.

At the same time, if you think finding new job may take 2-6 months, this could be a big factor to consider as well.

In my case I had the notice period for one month and I made my mind to find job during that time and even if required, I decided to take a month's break. I had different situation and I am sure, the action on this situation would be different based on individual circumstances.

This is what I did, I took my chance. In my case, I was moved to the different team.

My suggestion: Please make a list of pros and cons, weigh your options, think carefully about the advantages or disadvantages of discussion or quitting company without discussion before making a final decision.

I wish you good luck with whatever you decide :)